# Schedule a task with a non administrator account - Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I'm trying to schedule a windows task from the command line with an un-elevated account but I'm getting access denied.

The code I'm using is:

```
schtasks /create /tn Cleanup /tr powershell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\cleanup.ps1" /sc minute /mo 1 /NP
```

Is there a way to schedule a task without supplying a user/pass? (using the already logged in account credentials)

Comment: access denied from what? scheduling the task, or when the task executes?

Comment: @MarcB while scheduling. `schtasks /create...`

Comment: You need to supply credentials when you create a task for the scheduled task to run as the account specified, otherwise it will use your own account by default. Also whatever your running will need an account that has sufficient rights to complete the task.

Comment: @NickEagle I'm using the administrator account but I still get `(ERROR: Access is denied}`. I'm not supplying any credentials.

Comment: You need to elevate command prompt and use an account with administrative rights to create the task (run command prompt as administrator), once its created you can use a normal account assuming it has enough access to complete the task.

Comment: @NickEagle I need to use the command line (in order to create a task in several computers) and I'm not getting any UAC prompt, the command just hangs.

Comment: You need to start Command line as administrator before you execute the command. Though the below should be able to do what you require for several computers

Answer (score 0):

Ok using Powershell you should be able to achieve this by doing the following

```
$Computers = "Computer1","Computer2","Computer3"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c schtasks /create /tn Cleanup /tr powershell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\cleanup.ps1 /sc minute /mo 1 /NP" }
}
```

You may need to select an account that is an admin for all the systems.

Comment: For test purposes,  I'm trying to do this on local computer, is the var `$computer` the same as `$env:COMPUTERNAME` ?

Comment: Yep that's correct. I suspect that your want to make a copy of the ps1 file to each of the computers as well.

Comment: I'm getting `The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request` is there any specific service that needs to be enabled fort this to work ?

Comment: You need to configure your client and remote clients to accept remote management commands by doing the following in an elevated command prompt, WinRM quickconfig

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and explanation but I'm searching for a solution that doesn't involve extra configuration and elevated command prompt.

Comment: Other other way would be to use GPO or perhaps a login script